# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.sar.pkg.MyServlet

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, web-applications

**MyServlet.java**

```
    class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //private static final long serialVersionUID =102831973239L;
    static String  task;
    public MyServlet(){

    }
    String tm; 
     protected  void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         task = request.getParameter("task");
         tm= request.getParameter("reminder_time");
         try {
             SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
             Date time=new Date();
             formatter.format(time);
        try{    
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reminder","sarthak","sar31thak");  
             String INSERT_RECORD = "insert into ToDo values(?, ?)";
                      PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
                      pstmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_RECORD);
                      pstmt.setString(1, task);
                      pstmt.setDate(2, (java.sql.Date) time);
                      int rs= pstmt.executeUpdate();

            if(rs!=0){
                response.sendRedirect("success.html");
                return;
                    }
            else{
                response.sendRedirect("error.html");
            }
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
System.out.println("Got an EXCEPTION");}  
        } 
         catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Got an ERROR");
        }
             }
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Alert</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sar.pkg.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Which causes the following error

HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.sar.pkg.MyServlet

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class com.sar.pkg.MyServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.sar.pkg.MyServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause 
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager can not access a member of class com.sar.pkg.MyServlet with modifiers "public"
    sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

**I have tried to remove this error by using different serialVersionID and cleaned the project before running it. Still stuck on this. PLease help. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Your class should be public. `task` and `tm` *must* be local variables, not member variables: otherwise your servlet is not thread-safe. You are not defending properly against missing or invalid parameters. The `format()` method returns a value which you are throwing away. The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been required since 2007. You've disclosed your database password. You are leaking the `PreparedStatement` in all cases, and the connection in both the success and the exception cases. Printing your own error message imstead of an exception is unacceptable. Your code formatting is execrable.

Comment: Can you help me out here? I am new to java coding.

Comment: I have already done so, in considersble detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Servlet class `com.sar.pkg.MyServlet` is not public. Your definition

```
    class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
```

should be

```
    public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
```